# How does SpaceX phased array system work to keep track on the rocket

Tags: spacex, falcon-9

I have heard that SpaceX uses some kind of phased array system. I guess, this is reasonable because the speed of the rocket makes usage of any movable parts impossible.

However, I am not an engineer and want to know, how they position the system around the starting and landing pads to allow 3D positioning of the tracked device. I also wonder which frequency and tx power is necessary and what hardware the rocket has to interact with the system?

Comment: Looks great! fyi I've just asked [What were those motorized human-piloted platforms with helical antennas called (tracking launches)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23646/12102)

Comment: Oh, this might be helpful/interesting: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8061/12102 It's an R&D effort, not used in routine launches as you are asking about here.

Comment: I also think it is an interesting question, and I belive the systems works similar to beamforming in the upcoming 5g standard

Comment: The speed of the rocket is not too high to use a parabolic dish as the antenna. You just have to make the drive motors powerful enough to keep up. Nasa used to use human-aimed cameras for tracking, slow human reflexes would be more of a bottleneck than slewing a dish.

Answer (score 3):

KSC has a [640 antenna system](https://www.fastcompany.com/3048337/making-rocket-launches-a-breeze-nasa-unveils-a-new-wind-measurement-system) to track wind shear at the launch site up to about 60000 feet. It is not used for tracking.

The air force at Cape Canaveral air force station houses the 45th space wing, which operates the TEL-4 tracking station. It seems to be vital for launches and there are no launches when it doesn't work. Unfortunately, no more information available on this.

There is a TDRSS tracking and data satellite system, which is a network of satellites to track rockets and satellites and it is the current system for tracking and launch support.

Also, since you wrote you *heard* this, sometimes many antennas are referred to as an "array of antennas", but this does not mean, they are operating together or are phased.

Comment: With heard I mean, some info I got from related companies. So it is very likely that they use phased arrays, but I got no details about the system itself. Beside this, I think it is smart to use phased arrays :D

Comment: Can you add a link or reference that supports "KSC has a 640 antenna system"? I don't doubt it, but in stackexchange facts like that cited in answers need to be supported, and wow I'd love to read about it further (as might future readers). Since it's such a specific number, it must be coming from somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: It would have been nice to have that wind profiler when I was working shuttle DOLILU!

Comment: Who are you again?