# What were those motorized human-piloted platforms with helical antennas called (tracking launches)?

Tags: antenna

[This interesting question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23641/12102) got me started. I have these vignettes in my Apollo-era memory of antenna systems that tracked launches for telemetry. They had maybe four end-fire helical antennas pointing toward the rocket, and were motorized for tracking. I seem to remember a person sat on them to do manual visual tracking with a telescope.

Am I mixing two different systems together (an optical telescope with human tracking and an automatic-tracking antenna) or were there antennas that were human guided?

Could someone let me know if they existed, and perhaps post an image and/or link to a system description?

---

Here are images of each aspect separately; a human-guided optical tracking camera, and an articulated quad array of end-fire helical antennas. Were they ever combined?

[image]

**above:** Contraves-Goerz Kineto Tracking Mount (KTM), from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Contraves-Goerz_Kineto_Tracking_Mount.jpeg).

[image]

**above:** "Satellite tracking-aquisition antenna, Pleumeur-Bodou, France. This type of antenna is called a Helical antenna. It transmits and receives circularly polarized radio waves, which are widely used for satellite communication." From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Traqueur_acquisition.JPG).

Comment: I'm not in a position to do much research today but STS at least had KTM trailers which were human-pointed optical systems. Perhaps this will aid your search. https://appel.nasa.gov/2011/09/26/ata_4-7_shuttle_tracker-html/

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks! I've added an image of a KTM, that's just the kind of thing I was thinking of.

Comment: I ran across this beautiful shot by Richard Avedon. It's from a photoshoot he did at the Cape.  https://live.staticflickr.com/630/23605895202_a8029bef86_b.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble that's *really incredible!!* Okay, next trip to the library starts in the photography section. I'd never seen his work, but a quick search shows that I'm going to have to.Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be surprised if there was a need for human-in-the-loop control of a quad [axial-mode helical antenna](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/travelling/helix.php) like that.

The main lobe (1/2 gain) of a antenna like that probably covers about +/-15 degrees; there's little need for fine pointing.

On the other hand, they're really photogenic:

[image]

The [NASA caption](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_757.html) says in part:

> Is this a scene from a corny science fiction movie of the 1950s? This 1951 image actually is of scientists at the Jet Propulsion Laboratory (JPL) who were working on missile development for the U.S. Army.
>
> In order to receive data signals from missiles in flight, JPL also developed telemetering ground equipment. The system included these helical antennas as well as receivers, recording equipment, gas-powered generators and batteries for power, and telephones for communication between primary and secondary telemetering sites. All the equipment, including a control room, was installed in trucks so it could be easily transported and set up in the field. The directional antennas were mounted on top of 35-foot telephone poles. During testing, each antenna was steered using a small wheel, like a ship's wheel, near the bottom of the pole, attached to the antenna by rope.

It's possible you're remembering a photo where [somebody was posing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hammer_Ace_SATCOM_Antenna.jpg) with the antennas.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! After reading this and thinking further, I may be remembering some ancient footage of a missile test, maybe even a heat-seeking missile where the trajectory could be quite unpredictable.

Comment: Not Apollo related, but we had a "tri-helix' antenna at Tonopah test range. It was three helical antennae arranged to have a large coverage, large enough that they were statically aimed. If I recall correctly, it was P band, maybe 225-260MHz. But it wasn't actively tracking.  I'll look around to see if I can find a picture.