# Where is the "antenna farm" from which this Soyuz launch photo was taken?

Tags: identify-this-object, tracking, roscosmos, baikonur-cosmodrome

The Phys.org article [SpaceX Christmas delivery arrives at space station](https://phys.org/news/2018-12-spacex-christmas-delivery-space-station.html)
 had a small version of this photo, and I found this large one at wirenews.com's [SpaceX Christmas delivery arrives at space station](https://www.winknews.com/2018/12/08/spacex-holiday-care-package-delivered-to-space-station/)

I think that the object in the background (zoomed, sharpened, and cropped below) is the same or similar to the one shown in [Why have four parabolas on a ground-side array instead of just a single large one](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30399/12102)

A map, or shot with google maps showing where this is would be great!

[image]

[image]

> n this photo taken with a long exposure, a Soyuz rocket carrying a new crew to the International Space Station blasts off from the Russian-leased Baikonur cosmodrome in Kazakhstan, Monday, Dec. 3, 2018. The Russian rocket carries U.S. astronaut Anne McClain, Russian cosmonaut Oleg Kononenko‎ and CSA astronaut David Saint Jacques. (AP Photo/Dmitri Lovetsky)

Comment: @QiLinXue it's okay if your answer has some amount overlap with the other answer, I don't think it's necessary to delete it after you obviously put some work into it. You also have new information and links that would be interesting to others Consider undeleting? It's also a good way to pick up your first few reputation points. fyi users with rep above 10,000 can still see deleted answers anyway. Thanks, and Welcome to Space!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This IP-1 site at Baikonur cosmodrome 
https://kik-sssr.ru/IP_1_Turatam_Foto.htm

A few examples of other views of the antenna arrays in the question from there:

[image: IP-1 site at Baikonur cosmodrome from kik-sssr.ru/IP_1_Turatam_Foto(dot)htm]

[image: IP-1 site at Baikonur cosmodrome from kik-sssr.ru/IP_1_Turatam_Foto(dot)htm]

[image: IP-1 site at Baikonur cosmodrome from kik-sssr.ru/IP_1_Turatam_Foto(dot)htm]

[image: IP-1 site at Baikonur cosmodrome from kik-sssr.ru/IP_1_Turatam_Foto(dot)htm]

Comment: This is excellent, I'm now in "antenna heaven", Thank you!

Comment: The entrance in "antenna heaven" is here - http://kik-sssr.ru/Map_KIK_SSSR.htm

Comment: Yes indeed! Hey I have a question. When I click on НИП-17 (in Yakutsk Якутск) there is another quad dish: http://kik-sssr.ru/17_Yakutsk/i0295rp.jpg I had thought there was only one of these near Baikonur. I wonder how many of this kind of antenna there are! The question [Why have four parabolas on a ground-side array instead of just a single large one](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30399/12102) and all of the answers focus only on only Baikonur, and so far nobody can demonstrate exactly how it works. Do you think the photo was posted here at НИП-17 just randomly?

Comment: Many more photos of this here as well, in fact there are two in two photos!  http://kik-sssr.ru/17.3_Tehzona_Yakutsk.htm  here: http://kik-sssr.ru/17.3_Tehzona_Yakutsk/i0303rp.jpg and here: http://kik-sssr.ru/17.3_Tehzona_Yakutsk/i0336rp.jpg  Perhaps I should ask "How many" as a separate question?

Comment: This is a standard "Romashka"("Chamomile") telemetry station. They were installed at all tracking stations and ships. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MA-9_Romashka.jpg https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Missile_range_instrumentation_ship_"Marshal_Nedelin"_in_1985.jpeg http://www.svengrahn.pp.se/radioind/Ships/Ships.htm https://www.kik-sssr.ru/Antenns.htm

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, these are quite standard and were used in many different locations, even on tracking ships.

Answer (score 4):

The quad parabola is in the "radio-engineering center" (loose translation) [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/45%C2%B055'13.0%22N+63%C2%B020'32.0%22E/@45.9093886,63.3327953,508m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d45.920278!4d63.342222?hl=en) You can't see it well in that Google image, but it shows up clearly in this image of the same area from Apple Maps:
[image]

The two trapezoidal antennae are to the south east. Again, hard to see on Google, but visible on the Apple version
[image]
(which can be zoomed form this).  Looking at the various locations, I think the picture was taken some somewhere near the blue circle, which on Google maps is [here](https://www.google.com/maps/@45.9055459,63.3381712,507m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en).  That's also consist with a launch that's generally northeast.

Comment: @uhoh - [Google Maps version](https://www.google.com/maps/place/45.909707,+63.334027/@45.9096207,63.3340051,18z/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en) is quite poor. It's (walking distance) SSW of "Gagarin's Start", a tourist attraction. OTOH, [Bing Earth](https://zoom.earth/#45.909695,63.334102,18.8z,sat) gives a reasonable view. A [few dozen sources](https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Gagarin%27s_Start&params=45.920278_N_63.342222_E_) for that location if you wish to browse.

Comment: Oh I will check those now, thanks! btw I have just asked [What is the name of this space museum in Russian and does it have a website and/or virtual tour site?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32724/12102)

Comment: @uhoh - That comment *might* answer that partially, I am busy for an hour - I'll check back but likely will be beaten to the punch.