# Who designed the cool-looking Orbita Molniya tracking station at Khabarovsk? What does it look like inside?

Tags: russia, soviet-union, commercial, space-art, ground-station

Wikipedia's [Orbita (TV system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbita_(TV_system)) says:

> Orbita (Russian: орбита) is a Soviet-Russian system of broadcasting and delivering TV signals via satellites. It is considered to be the first national network of satellite television.
>
> The Orbita system is based on communication satellites in highly elliptical Molniya orbits, as well as on many ground downlink TV stations for reception and relaying TV signals to antennas of TV sets of many local areas. The full deployment of the Orbita satellite system took place on 25 October 1967 when ground downlink stations of some cities of Soviet Siberia and the Far East began to receive regular TV programmes from Moscow-based uplink stations via a constellation of Molniya satellites.

and includes the image below, of a large dish on an altitude/azimuth mount. I used this in [How exactly did ground stations track the early Molniya satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54947/12102) where I've asked about what it was like to track them, but after taking a second look at the photo I realize this station actually a cool piece of architecture as well.

The station sits directly below the dish. It looks like it's either one high story or has two stories, both with windows, and the upper part with 45 degree angled windows all around; a bit like a space ship.

The rectangular cross-section support pillars of the weight of the dish distributed around the circumference appear to be angled in different directions rather than radially.

I'm really curious about the architect and the work they did to make the satellite tracking station both solid/functional and attractive and somewhat futuristic-looking.

**Question:** Who designed the cool-looking Orbita Molniya tracking station at Khabarovsk? What does it look like inside?

---

[image: Orbita ground station. Khabarovsk 1977 (cropped)]

[image: Orbita ground station. Khabarovsk 1977] click for larger, [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_1977.jpg)

> Orbita ground station. [Khabarovsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khabarovsk). 1977

Comment: related: [How exactly did ground stations track the early Molniya satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54947/12102)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner hall can be seen, for example, here.
[image]
https://anthrax-urbex.livejournal.com/36886.html
https://bu33er.livejournal.com/247978.html

Comment: Perhaps not 100% realistic, but this is nice https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/9311/81396818.4/0_ee1a9_60b7a8c1_orig

Comment: @uhoh  A slightly different design at the northernmost station. https://sergeydolya.livejournal.com/1110661.html

Comment: Oh! The design seems to be inspired by a yurt https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_wooden_yurt_under_construction_in_Zakamensky_district_of_Buryatia,_Russia.jpg

Comment: @uhoh Ordinary physics and geometry. One more example https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Transmiter_P-400.jpg